# Only default controller is accessing on live site code igniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My Codeigniter website is working on localhost. without index.php page and is working for all pages. but when I uploaded on live server it cannot access other controller and function except default controller(index) function.

Here is my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Here my config file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://blog.stockmarketislive.com';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: "without index.php page and is working for all pages" - what do you mean "without index.php page"? The `index.php` file would seem to be an integral part of Codeignitor?

Comment: Make sure you have `mod_rewrite` installed and enabled on the web server. You also have to have the setting `AllowOverride all` for the vhost (if it is `none` or missing, .htacess files won't be read).

Comment: user82217 Its working with index.php for all controller and functions. but without index.php it accessing only default controller

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this .htaccess code....

```
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```